# Modeling with Support Vector Machine in regression problem

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, machine-learning, estimation

I have 20 independent variables(explanatory)and 1 dependent(respond) variable and I wish to use SVM as a regression problem to predict my dependent variable. but the point is that my independent(explanatory)variables are ranging differently.

e.g 
 {x1 < 0} , {x2 > 0} ,
 {-1

The question is that:

Am I allow to use these explanatory variables in my SVM Regression model without normalizing them? or I should normal them first and then use them to estimate my respond variable?

If I should normal them, is there any specific normalization formula?

Comment: It depends... Do your independent variables (predictors) have the same unit (and you shouldn't rescale them)? Otherwise, SVM generally works better if your predictors have similar magnitude (in which case using a simple function like scale in R would work).

Comment: actually, the predictors are from several sources with different units. 
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ah I see. Then it probably makes sense to rescale them.